# Unable To Displaying Comments On A Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, comments

I am adding comments to a post which save fine but I have been struggling to get them show more than one comments on a post. When I save it only shows the first comment posted.

Comments Controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @micropost = Micropost.find_by(id: params[:micropost_id])
    @comment = 
@micropost.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:body))
    if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Comment Posted"
    end
    redirect_to current_user
  end

end

def show
  @comment = Comment.find_by(id: params[:id])
end
```

end

In the view I have:

```
  <%= @comments.body %>
```

I can show one comment, but when I write another the first one only shows. I tried to loop over them in the view with a do loop but I then get an error stating `undefined method .each for "text from comment":String`

Maybe my show @comment needs improving or is there something I have to do in the view to get them all to display. The same do loops works for the posts, but I can seem to get it working for the comments.

I also have another minor issue when there is no comments saved, I can't view the post at all because there is no body existing. I assume I will have to write some sort of if/else to state if there is no body, display anyway.

Comment: where you are displaying your comments?In post detail page?

Comment: The error you are getting when trying to loop over the comments in the view is because `.each` is not available on a String but only on an array and hash. If you are doing `@comments.body.each` that won't work because, I'm assuming, the body is a string. You could try `@comments.each`. But I'm not sure where `@comments` is being defined, is it meant to be `@commment`?

Comment: @KrupaSuthar I am displaying the comments in on post show page.

Comment: @codeinaire that makes sense about looping over  a string. Sorry yes that should be @ comment in the view.  Do I need to turn all the strings i.e. comments into an array and then iterate over them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your posts controller's show method you should fetch comments and then you can show it in html page.

For example,

```
def show
 @post = Post.includes(:comments).find(params[:id])
end
```

and in your view file, you can iterate over comments like below,

```
@post.comments.each do |comment|
# you logic here
end
```

Comment: It took a little bit of play about but this one pretty much got me there. It displays them all together, but i will have to figure something out to separate them. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

what you are doing is fetching single comment and try to loop through that object , which is not possible.

what you want to do is display all the comments posted on 'Micropost' so what you need to do is just pass micropost_id in params and user where query like below

```
@comments = Comment.where(micropost_id: params[:micropost_id])
```

then you can loop through that object in your .erb template

```
<% @comments.each do|comment| %>
  <%= comment.body %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I feel this one is extremely close. I have tried it out and it saves I can display the post, but no comments are displaying. When getting the page with the comments the console shows the following. `
  Comment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."micropost_id" IS NULL
  Rendered comments/_comments.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered microposts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (16.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 93ms (Views: 88.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)`

Comment: The micropost_id is showing up as null for some reason.

Comment: If I check out the comments table there is micropost_id present `#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Comment id: 1, body: "Testing this comment section out baby", created_at: "2019-07-30 11:22:07", updated_at: "2019-07-30 11:22:07", micropost_id: 1>`

Comment: If I add `@comments = Comment.find_by(id: params[:id])` to be my controller and `<%= @comment.body %>` to my view it will display one comment. But if I try and loop over that it doesn't work as it is string. So I am almost there. I just need to be get them in a way so as which I can loop over them.

Comment: you should debug that are you getting , params[:micropost_id], if not then you should try to sort out that first, if you are not able to get that micropost_id, and you are only able to get params[:id], which is comment id , then you should write messy query like @comments = Comment.where(micropost_id: Comment.find(params[:id]).micropost_id) , but i suggest you should not follow this approach , instead you should try to get micropost_id, from params.